# Socket timeout! issue in Telnet connection using node telnet-client

Tags: node.js, sockets, npm

My requirement is to connect to Telnet client from node js.

I am using [telnet-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telnet-client) package

I am using this code for connection

```
var Telnet = require('telnet-client')
var connection = new Telnet()

var params = {
  host: '127.0.0.1',
  port: 23,
  shellPrompt: '/ # ',
  timeout: 1500,
  // removeEcho: 4
}

connection.on('ready', function(prompt) {
connection.exec(cmd, function(err, response) {
console.log(response)
  })
})

connection.on('timeout', function() {
console.log('socket timeout!')
connection.end()
})

connection.on('close', function() {
  console.log('connection closed')
})

connection.connect(params)`
```

But it always return "socket timeout!" in console.

I also tried by adding 'username' and 'password' details in params

```
`var params = {
        host: '127.0.0.1',
        port: 23,
        shellPrompt: '/ #',
        loginPrompt: 'Username: ',
        passwordPrompt: 'Password: ',
        username: 'vinit',
        password: 'vinit123',
        initialLFCR: true,
        timeout: 1500,
        // removeEcho: 4
}`
```

but still facing the same issue. In some links i found people saying that `shellPrompt` value is incorrect then what should be the value of `shellPrompt`. actually i am completely new to this topic so don't have much idea about it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you try to change timeout value?

Comment: @hasbi Yes i tried by changing it to 10000 but still showing same result.

Comment: Could you make it -1?

Comment: i cannot set it negetive.. on setting it to -1 i get this error "Unhandled rejection RangeError: "msecs" argument must be a non-negative finite number................."

Comment: Could you add callback to log the 'connect' event. This should tell you if and when the TCP connection is established.

Comment: @sborsky yes i tried that .. the connect event was called before time out.. it first print log from connect event and then goes to timeout

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your comments, that is not a networking connectivity issue, which means that your connection fails either during the login, or it fails to detect the valid prompt afterwards (and then waits for it until it times out).

So the first thing you should do, is add the `failedLogin` callback:

```
connection.on('failedlogin',function(msg) {
    console.log("Login failed !",msg);
});
```

To detect the "failed login" case (otherwise it will attempt to login once, and then hang until the timeout comes).

Next, connect to your server "by hand", i.e. by running `telnet 127.0.0.1` from the command line, and review what the "login/password" and "shell" prompts do look like.

E.g. on my "Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS" system:

```
%telnet 127.0.0.1
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to 127.0.0.1.
Escape character is '^]'.
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
zeppelin-desktop login: zeppelin
Password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.4.0-97-generic x86_64)

* Documentation:  https://help.ubuntu.com
* Management:     https://landscape.canonical.com
* Support:        https://ubuntu.com/advantage

zeppelin@zeppelin-desktop:~$
```

- The login prompt is `zeppelin-desktop login:`
- The password prompt is `Password:`
- The shell prompt is `zeppelin@zeppelin-desktop:~$`

Login and password prompts **do match** their predefined patterns in [telnet-client](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telnet-client).

> loginPrompt: Username/login prompt that the host is using. Can be a string or an instance of RegExp. Defaults to regex '/login[: ]*$/i'.
>
> passwordPrompt: Password/login prompt that the host is using. Can be a string or an instance of RegExp. Defaults to regex '/Password: /i'.

So there is no need to change them.

Shell prompt **does not match** the the predefined pattern (`/ #`):

> shellPrompt: Shell prompt that the host is using. Can be a string or an instance of RegExp. Defaults to regex '/(?:/ )?#\s/'.

so it needs to be modified, e.g.

```
shellPrompt: /:~[^$]*\$\s*$/,
```

You can test your shell prompt pattern with grep, like that:

```
%echo 'zeppelin@zeppelin-desktop:~$' | grep -o  ':~[^$]*\$\s*$'
:~$
```

(the output will be empty if it does not match)

Now that you have a correct shell prompt pattern, `telnet-client` should be able to identify it, and send the `cmd` (in the `on('ready')` handler) to server, in response to it.

E.g. if you set `cmd="date"`, you should get the current date in response:

```
connection.on('ready', function(prompt) {
    console.log(">date");
    connection.exec("date", function(err, response) {
       console.log("<",response)
    })
})

%nodejs telnet.js
>date
< Wed Oct 25 10:11:11 UTC 2017
```

P.S.

Another option you may want to set is the "failed login" pattern:

```
failedLoginMatch : "Login incorrect"
```

to detect the server rejecting your password.

This is not strictly necessary on my Ubuntu system, as it will just
repeat the login prompt in case of failed password, so that `failedlogin` event will be dispatched anyway, but depending on your configuration,
it might be required.

Comment: Although. i already solved it by myself. But it is correct answer. Thanks for posting it. it will help others

Answer (score 0):

This is a connect timeout: there is no Telnet server running at the target IP:port, or that port is blocked in the target firewall.

Comment: I can connect to same from terminal. So, credentials are correct.

Comment: Do you have any idea about value of `shellPrompt` i found at some places that it might be because value of shell prompt me be incorrect. In that case how can i find that for my ubuntu system.